# Understanding the in operator in Python

Tags: python

```
index = []

def add_to_index(index,keyword,url):
    if len(index) == 0:
        index.append([keyword, [url]])
    elif keyword in index:
        find_key_pos = index.find(keyword)
        index.insert(find_key_pos + len(keyword), url)

add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://udacity.com')
add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://npr.org')
print(index)
```

My output is:

```
[['udacity', ['http://udacity.com']]]
```

Actually the output has to be

```
[['udacity', ['http://udacity.com', 'http://npr.org']]
```

Whenever the keyword already exists in the index list, I just have to insert the url to the list that is next to the keyword.
In,

```
add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://udacity.com')
add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://npr.org')
```

The keyword 'udacity' is the same that is why I should add the different url's after that keyword.

Comment: Why don't you use a dict for your problem.?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. There's no return statement in function. For each function call `index` is empty. You need to store those values in the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your bugs:

```
index.insert(find_key_pos + len(keyword), url)
```

The first parameter to `list.insert()` is the index for the new element. You actually only want to get the list for your keyword though and append a new URL to the nested list.

What you want instead is:

```
index[find_key_pos].append(url)
```

Second bug lies in the re-use of the `index` variable. Your function parameter is shadowing the list from the parent scope. Use different names. Your code will work, because lists are mutable and you are passing around references to the same list, but it will create a hella lot of confusion down the road.

---

But what you should really do is you should look up Python dictionaries. They offer the keyword functionality out of the box.

Here's a small dict wrapper that will make your life easier:

```
class ListDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = ()

    def addEntry(self, key, entry):
        if key in self.index:
            self.index[key].append(entry)
        else:
            self.index[key] = [entry]

    def getEntries(self, key):
        if key in self.index:
            return self.index[key]
        else:
            return []
```

Usage:

```
websiteUrls = ListDict()
websiteUrls.addEntry("udemy", "foo")
websiteUrls.addEntry("udemy", "bar")
websiteUrls.getEntries("udemy")
# ["foo", "bar"]
websiteUrls.getEntries("nope")
# []
```